# Why DateTime.new returns year only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, yaml, seed

I want to seed DateTime in seeds.rb from YAML file

this is code from seeds.rb

```
created_at: DateTime.new("#{post['created_at']}".to_i)
```

and in posts YAML file:

```
created_at: 2010-04-16
```

Output of this is `created_at: "2010-01-01 00:00:00"`

Question is: In what format should be created_at in YAML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse):

```
DateTime.parse('2010-04-16')
#⇒ Fri, 16 Apr 2010 00:00:00 +0000
```

For your example:

```
created_at: DateTime.parse(post['created_at'])
```

---

If `post['created_at']` is already an instance of `DateTime` (e.g. loaded with YAML,) just assign it as is:

```
created_at: post['created_at']
```

Comment: got an error: TypeError: no implicit conversion of DateTime into String

Comment: That error message most likely means `post['created_at']` is already a `DateTime` instance and you don’t need to do anything with it.

Comment: yes, actually I didn't need to add DateTime.parse nor DateTime.new, just post['created_at'] works :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you check `"2010-04-16".to_i` then you get 2010. So you call `DateTime.new(2010)` and get the result you see.

You can't use a string itself, with `DateTime.new("2010-04-16")` you get a type error.

But Yaml converts already to a Date when it parses `2010-04-16`, so I guess you can use `post['created_at'].to_datetime`

Full raw ruby example:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'date'
post = YAML.load('created_at: 2010-04-16')
p post['created_at']  #-> #<Date: 2010-04-16 ((2455303j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
p post['created_at'].to_datetime #-> #<DateTime: 2010-04-16T00:00:00+00:00 ((2455303j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Your seeds.rb may look like

```
created_at: post['created_at'].to_datetime
```

Comment: I got an ArgumentError: comparison of DateTime with 0 failed

Comment: `DateTime.new` in the last line looks a bit redundant :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin You are right ;)  I corrected it